# Python local variable losing reference

Tags: python, variables, reference

I'm developing a SDN Controller with Ryu Framework in Python.

I'm facing a strange problem, maybe an easy one since it's my first time programming in Python. I have the following sentence:

```
@set_ev_cls(ofp_event.EventOFPPacketIn, MAIN_DISPATCHER)
   def _packet_in_handler(self, ev):
        # If you hit this you might want to increase
        # the "miss_send_length" of your switch
        if ev.msg.msg_len < ev.msg.total_len:
            self.logger.debug("packet truncated: only %s of %s bytes",
                          ev.msg.msg_len, ev.msg.total_len)
        msg = ev.msg
        datapath = msg.datapath
        ofproto = datapath.ofproto
        parser = datapath.ofproto_parser
        in_port = msg.match['in_port']

        pkt = packet.Packet(msg.data)
        eth = pkt.get_protocols(ethernet.ethernet)[0]

        pkt_ip = pkt.get_protocol(ipv4.ipv4)
        ipv4_src = None
        ipv4_dst = None

        if pkt_ip is not None:
            print "pkt_ip is not none"
            ipv4_src = pkt_ip.src
            ipv4_dst = pkt_ip.dst
            print ipv4_src
            print ipv4_dst

        if eth.ethertype == ether_types.ETH_TYPE_LLDP:
            # ignore lldp packet
            return
        dst = eth.dst
        src = eth.src

        dpid = datapath.id
        self.mac_to_port.setdefault(dpid, {})

        self.logger.info("packet in %s %s %s %s", dpid, src, dst, in_port)
        self.logger.info("learn a mac address")
        # learn a mac address to avoid FLOOD next time.
        self.mac_to_port[dpid][src] = in_port

        if dst in self.mac_to_port[dpid]:
            out_port = self.mac_to_port[dpid][dst]
        else:
            out_port = ofproto.OFPP_FLOOD

        actions = [parser.OFPActionOutput(out_port)]

        #print "before avoid packet_in"
        #print ipv4_src

        # install a flow to avoid packet_in next time
        self.logger.info("install a flow to avoid packet_in next time")
        if out_port != ofproto.OFPP_FLOOD:
           print "into if out_port"
           print ipv4_src
           print in_port
           print dst
           match = parser.OFPMatch(in_port=in_port, eth_dst=dst)
           # verify if we have a valid buffer_id, if yes avoid to send both
           # flow_mod & packet_out
        if msg.buffer_id != ofproto.OFP_NO_BUFFER:
            self.add_flow(datapath, 1, match, actions, msg.buffer_id)
            return
        else:
            self.add_flow(datapath, 1, match, actions)
    data = None
    if msg.buffer_id == ofproto.OFP_NO_BUFFER:
        data = msg.data

    out = parser.OFPPacketOut(datapath=datapath,buffer_id=msg.buffer_id, in_port=in_port, actions=actions, data=data)

    self.logger.info("send_msg_out")
    print out
    datapath.send_msg(out)
    self.logger.info("sent send_msg_out in packet_in")
```

When I am not passing `ipv4_src` as parameter ( `match = parser.OFPMatch(in_port=in_port, eth_dst=dst)` ), the code runs ok. The variables are printed and no errors.

However, when I'm passing `ipv4_src` as parameter ( `match = parser.OFPMatch(in_port=in_port, eth_dst=dst ipv4_src=ipv4_src)` ), I always get 'None' in the `print dst` and the `parser.OFPMatch` returns me a length error (of course, as it is getting 'None').

Independently of using *ipv4_src* as parameter in *parser.OFPMatch*, *in_port* and *dst* are always printed succesfully.

Does it have something to do with some Python characteristic I'm skipping?

**EDITED:**

See two output examples:

- Not using ipv4_src as parameter:

  `into if out_port
  192.168.1.200
  2
  00:00:00:00:00:01`
- Using ipv4_src as parameter:

  `into if out_port
  None
  2
  00:00:00:00:00:01`

When I use *ipv4_src* I get the following (because the method is getting 'None' it cannot get his length, I suppose):

```
into if out_port
None
1
00:00:00:00:00:02
SimpleSwitch13: Exception occurred during handler processing. Backtrace from offending handler [_packet_in_handler] servicing event [EventOFPPacketIn] follows.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ryu/ryu/ryu/base/app_manager.py", line 290, in _event_loop
handler(ev)
  File "/home/ryu/ryu/ryu/app/simple_switch_13.py", line 134, in _packet_in_handler
self.add_flow(datapath, 1, match, actions, msg.buffer_id)
  File "/home/ryu/ryu/ryu/app/simple_switch_13.py", line 68, in add_flow
datapath.send_msg(mod)    
  File "/home/ryu/ryu/ryu/controller/controller.py", line 289, in send_msg
msg.serialize()
  File "/home/ryu/ryu/ryu/ofproto/ofproto_parser.py", line 211, in serialize
self._serialize_body()
  File "/home/ryu/ryu/ryu/ofproto/ofproto_v1_3_parser.py", line 2655, in _serialize_body
match_len = self.match.serialize(self.buf, offset)
  File "/home/ryu/ryu/ryu/ofproto/ofproto_v1_3_parser.py", line 1008, in serialize
field_offset)
  File "/home/ryu/ryu/ryu/ofproto/oxx_fields.py", line 250, in _serialize
value_len = len(value)
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: which `print` statement is giving you the `None`?

Comment: Nothing stands out to me right away wrong with this. Does "pkt_ip is not none" get printed when you run? I feel that pkt_ip.src is `None`. I'm not familiar with the framework so I'm not sure why - if that's the case.

Comment: Hi David, I'm talking about the last print, before *match*. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hi freebie, yes, it does. See two output examples:

Not using ipv4_src as parameter:
192.168.1.200
2
00:00:00:00:00:01

Using ipv4_src as parameter:
into if out_port
None
1
00:00:00:00:00:02

Comment: Can you show more of your code? As is, `print dst` would raise a  `Name Error` as `dst` is previously undefined.

Comment: I would expect same error on `if out_port` and also on `print in_port`, and for the same reason. These variables aren't defined. Now if you're not getting an error on either of those statements, then you still need to resolve what's happening with your `dst`. The question is also unclear, as you're suggesting the print statement fails to produce correct results based on a *subsequent* statement in your program; that simply doesn't make any sense at all. But without seeing a clear example of what your code is doing, it's hard to guess what the problem might be.

Comment: Sure, please check the question now, David. I have just updated it.

Comment: I edited your question for clarity and to remove the unnecessary example code (as it could be confusing to see such incomplete code).

Comment: I don't know this framework at all, but the error does not make sense either. You have `if pkt_ip is not None:` then it suggests you're calling this function several times and anticipate a failure. The only argument used in `match = parser.OFPMatch` originating from `pkt_ip` specifically is `ipv4_src`. Equally, `OFPMatch` is hidden behind a single `if` clause with no `else`. Is it possible that one of multiple calls of this function fails the `if pkt_ip is not None` case but not  `out_port != ofproto.OFPP_FLOOD` and you're tricked into seeing a single event via `if` branches?

Comment: In other words, for `if pkt_ip is not None:` add `else: print ipv4_src TAKES DEFAULT NULL VALUE` and check that a default `None` value is not passing silently over multiple calls (because currently nothing would be printed). In that case, a long series of printouts might _look_ the same but with one hidden difference. Also, do you need more specific tags on this question as it might be framework specific?

Comment: Thank you for editing, David. @roganjosh I tried adding the else sentence but no success... The weird thing is that at the moment I pass *ipv4_src* as parameter in *parser.OFPMatch* "Python bugs"; otherwise the code runs ok, but I do need to use *ipv4_src* in the *match*. :(

Comment: This is the part that doesn't make sense though. Your code should run top-to-bottom in this function (as far as I can see). I can only think that it's multiple calls (for which I gave a suggestion; even though that didn't work, are you calling this function iteratively?) or framework/library related, in which case you need to add extra tags to the question. I do not know a way that `OFPMatch` could affect its _preceding_ print statement otherwise.

Comment: I did not added tag related to Ryu Framework, Mininet or SDN because I really think they do not have nothing to do with this problem. However, I can do add these tags if you think it will help. Yes, it is top-down, the method is called only once a new packet arrives to the controller (my code). Yeah, how can I method called after a attribution change the value of a variable? I do not think it´s a framework (Ryu) problem...

Comment: The only thing I can think of in this case is a debug `print` statement _everywhere_ and have every `if` have an `else` to pinpoint. But I'm not able to help you any further; you're possibly right that the extra tags don't matter but this is not a standard issue at all in Python as far as I am aware sorry. The only other thing that was in the back of my mind is that iterator objects can only be consumed once (e.g. `csv.reader` objects) but I don't think it applies. Best of luck mate.

Comment: Thank you @roganjosh. I have just updated the question with the full error I got from Python when passing *ipv4_src* as parameter. Let´s see if it helps. Thanks again.